# Error in Minimization of Logistic Regression

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I have recently tried to implement logistic regression in python, using BFGS method. But, unfortunately, I get an error in dimensions while using TNC method works fine for me. Dataset was taken from Andrew Ng Machine learning course.

Sorry for the code, I'm new in python:)
Here it is:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
from scipy.io import loadmat
from scipy.optimize import minimize

%pylab inline

def Sigmoid(z):
    return 1/(1 + np.exp(-z))

def CostFunction(theta, lambda_, X, y):
    m,n = X.shape
theta = theta.reshape((n, 1))
    y = y.reshape((m,1))
    z = X.dot(theta)
    J = - (1/m) * ((y.T).dot(np.log(Sigmoid((z))) + ((1 - y).T).dot(np.log(1 - Sigmoid(z))) + (lambda_)/(2*m) *((theta[1:].T).dot(theta[1:]))))

    return(J[0]);

def Gradient(theta, lambda_,X, y):
    m, n = X.shape
    theta = theta.reshape((n,1))
    y = y.reshape((m,1))
    grad = np.zeros((n,1))
    z = X.dot(theta)
    grad[0] = (1/m) * (X[:,0].T).dot(Sigmoid(z) - y)
    grad[1:n] = (1/m) * (X[:, 1:n].T).dot(Sigmoid(z) - y) + (lambda_/m) * theta[1:n]
    return(grad)

def ova(X, y, n_labels, lambda_):

    initial_theta = np.zeros((X.shape[1], 1)) #401x1
    all_theta = np.zeros((n_labels, X.shape[1])) #10x401
    for c in np.arange(1, n_labels+1):
        res = minimize(CostFunction, initial_theta, args=(lambda_, X, (y == c)*1), method='BFGS',
                   jac= Gradient, options={'maxiter':150})
        all_theta[c-1] = res.x
    return(all_theta)

def predict1(all_theta, X):
    probs = Sigmoid(X.dot(all_theta.T))
    return(np.argmax(probs, axis=1)+1)

weights = loadmat('ex3weights.mat')
weights.keys()

mat = loadmat('ex3data1.mat')  # load mat-file
xdata = mat['X']
ydata = mat['y']
Theta1, Theta2 = weights['Theta1'], weights['Theta2']
print(Theta1.shape, Theta2.shape)

y = pd.DataFrame(ydata)
X = pd.DataFrame(xdata)
m,n = X.shape
X = X.as_matrix()
y = y.as_matrix()

X = np.insert(X, 0, 1, axis = 1)

theta = ova(X, y, 10, 0.1)
```

And here's the error message I'm getting:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-76-cb508c948a6b> in <module>()
----> 1 theta = ova(X, y, 10, 0.1)

<ipython-input-68-f8aa55870333> in ova(X, y, n_labels, lambda_)
     30     for c in np.arange(1, n_labels+1):
     31         res = minimize(CostFunction, initial_theta, args=(lambda_, X, (y == c)*1), method='BFGS',
---> 32                        jac= Gradient, options={'maxiter':150})
     33         all_theta[c-1] = res.x
     34     return(all_theta)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py in minimize(fun, x0, args, method, jac, hess, hessp, bounds, constraints, tol, callback, options)
    442         return _minimize_cg(fun, x0, args, jac, callback, **options)
    443     elif meth == 'bfgs':
--> 444         return _minimize_bfgs(fun, x0, args, jac, callback, **options)
    445     elif meth == 'newton-cg':
    446         return _minimize_newtoncg(fun, x0, args, jac, hess, hessp, callback,

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py in _minimize_bfgs(fun, x0, args, jac, callback, gtol, norm, eps, maxiter, disp, return_all, **unknown_options)
    932             alpha_k, fc, gc, old_fval, old_old_fval, gfkp1 = \
    933                      _line_search_wolfe12(f, myfprime, xk, pk, gfk,
--> 934                                           old_fval, old_old_fval, amin=1e-100, amax=1e100)
    935         except _LineSearchError:
    936             # Line search failed to find a better solution.

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py in _line_search_wolfe12(f, fprime, xk, pk, gfk, old_fval, old_old_fval, **kwargs)
    763     ret = line_search_wolfe1(f, fprime, xk, pk, gfk,
    764                              old_fval, old_old_fval,
--> 765                              **kwargs)
    766 
    767     if ret[0] is None:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/linesearch.py in line_search_wolfe1(f, fprime, xk, pk, gfk, old_fval, old_old_fval, args, c1, c2, amax, amin, xtol)
     95         return np.dot(gval[0], pk)
     96 
---> 97     derphi0 = np.dot(gfk, pk)
     98 
     99     stp, fval, old_fval = scalar_search_wolfe1(

ValueError: shapes (401,1) and (401,1) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 401 (dim 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message below tells you some hint 
ValueError: shapes (401,1) and (401,1) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 401 (dim 0)
You think you are doing a 10x401.401x1 matric multiply. But it turns out both matrices are 401x1. The problem traces back from your def Gradient.